# Types of Joomla Plugin?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I've been reading about making Joomla Plugins and so far I've stumbled upon numerous "types" of Plugins like

[Profile Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) and [Content Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_content_plugin).

**Questions:**

1. Are there really types of Plugins? Or are these just convenient ways of naming them?
2. If there are really types, what are the other types?
3. Is there a list of the tutorials found above because I really find Joomla Docs very vague and not organized. I can't find any list containing these tutorials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [different types of plugin availabl](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events)e in Joomla,

1. Authentication
2. Captcha
3. Content
4. Editors
5. Extensions
6. Finder
7. Quick Icons
8. System
9. User

All the above are types (Means based on this type you can do chnages on particular sections).
for example the profile plugin allows you to access user profile, the content plugin allows you to alter the article content. and so on.

So you need to first check what type of plugin you have to create, like you need to access user data then create profile plugin. or content then content type.

The system plugin allows you to modify entire out put of page. You can see a [sample content plugin](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-plugin-development-tutorial) here

Hope it make sense..

Comment: can you please confirm that the above 9 terms (converted to all lowercase) are the values most appropriate to assign to the `group` attribute of my `<file>` declaration when I am creating my `pkg_packagename.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

A plugin is something that will extending the functionality of the system.

1. Yes they are the plugin
2. There are numerous types of plugins, Carousel, Photo Gallery and many more to name
3. This YouTube Video might help you => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd93be8YRNY